# Get the key/value pairs of a nested hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Please see the following hash:

```
params[:category] #=> {"category"=>{"name"=>"name1", "parent_id"=>1, "category"=>{"name"=>"name2"}}}
```

and the desired output :

```
params[:category] #=> {"category"=>{"name"=>"name1", "parent_id"=>1 }}
```

I've tried several things but none succeed

```
params[:category].delete(params[:category][...]
```

How can I get the key/value pairs of this nested hash in order to delete it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: category is nested in category again nested in category?

Comment: Hi apneadiving, yes category is nested in category. I know it's not a good practice to have several identical keys in a hash but i don't have the choice here..

Comment: Why don't you have a choice? Aren't you in control of the source code generating the hash?

Comment: Yes, the hash is an input source formatted in that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the hash is:

```
params[:category] = {"category"=>{"name"=>"name1", "parent_id"=>1, "category"=>{"name"=>"name2"}}}
```

Then use:

```
params[:category]['category'].delete('category')
params[:category]
=> {"category"=>{"name"=>"name1", "parent_id"=>1}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {"category"=>{"name"=>"name1", "parent_id"=>1, "category"=>{"name"=>"name2"}}}
h['category'].delete('category')
{"category"=>{"name"=>"name1", "parent_id"=>1}}
```

Third line is the result. Did you want to delete `category` key of `h['category']`?

Answer (score 0):

If the hash is:

```
params[:category] = {"category"=>{"name"=>"name1", "parent_id"=>1, "category"=>{"name"=>"name2"}}}
```

Then use:

```
params[:category]["category"].slice!("category")
```